# JavaScript For, functions and mixed return

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, renderer

Im creating my own version of a `MarkDown` render. My goal is to read a string or file line by line then return the `MD` rendered as `HTML`.  The problem im facing is my return and line by line functionaility is not-returning what I want and I dont know why. Ive tried debugging but everything seemed fine. Ive also tried chaning my for loop but still no luck.

```js
//function used to render MD for the user

function render(md){
    let code = ""; //For functions return

    let mdLines = md.split('\n');

    for(let i = 0; i < mdLines.length; i++){

        //Statements to see what kind of MD header a line is.
        //I only have these statments as I just started this and am still figuring how I want to approach.

        if(mdLines[i].slice(0, 1) == "#"){
           code += code.concat("<h1>" + mdLines[i].replace("#", "") + "</h1>")
        }

        else if(mdLines[i].slice(0, 2) == "##"){
           code += code.concat("<h2>" + mdLines[i].replace("##", "") + "</h2>")
        }

        else if(mdLines[i].slice(0, 3) == "###"){
           code += code.concat("<h3>" + mdLines[i].replace("###", "") + "</h3>")
        }

        else if(mdLines[i].slice(0, 4) == "####"){
           code += code.concat("<h4>" + mdLines[i].replace("#", "") + "</h4>")
        }

        else if(mdLines[i].slice(0, 5) == "#####"){
           code += code.concat("<h5>" + mdLines[i].replace("#", "") + "</h5>")
        }

        else if(mdLines[i].slice(0, 6) == "######"){
           code += code.concat("<h6>" + mdLines[i].replace("######", "") + "</h6>")
        }
    };
    
    return code;
}


//editor
//This is what the user's .js file would be.
//I have it set up like this for testing.

let text1 = "## he#llo \n there \n# yooo"
let text2 = "# he#llo \n there \n## yooo"

console.log(render(text1));
console.log(render(text2));
```

text1 returns `<h1># he#llo </h1><h1># he#llo </h1><h2> he#llo </h2>`
text2 reutrns `<h1> he#llo </h1>`

text1 should return `<h2>he#llo</h2> there <h1> yooo </h1>`
text2 should return `<h1> he#llo </h1> there <h2> yooo </h2>`

If someone could help me get the proper returns and some potentially reusable code for this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

Ive also looked up the issue with some select terms but it seems no one has documented my very specific issue.

### Follow Up

I originally had it as multiple `if` statements but changed it to `else if` to not make it a duplicate.

I would also like to shorten this code and not use multiple `else if` statements if possible. My theories would be regEX or `case`

***NOTE*** if you were looking to render MD without coding your own render there are many librays to help you do that.

Renders: https://byby.dev/js-markdown-libs

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans no duh. im checking what the line starts with and its not returning as I documented.

Comment: Remember that a line that starts with "###" also starts with "#".  You need to check those in the opposite order.  Or, check ONCE for a leading "#" and count them one by one to determine the header level.

Comment: At the very least, reverse your code and make them `else if` statements, because right now a line that starts with `#####` will hit the first `if`, match, "eat" the first `#`, then move on to the next `if`, see `#####`, _still match_, eat `##`, move on to the next `if`, sees `###`, _still match_ and it's all-round a bad time.

Comment: @TimRoberts can you post an answer so i can see more in-depth?

Comment: Also, let's be brutally honest here.  There are 1,000 Javascript packages to convert Markdown to HTML, most of them efficient and well-tested.  Why on earth would you want to re-invent the wheel? There are more interesting problems to tackle.

Comment: @TimRoberts I beleive thats my own business?

Comment: No, he has a perfectly valid point: SO is for real world answers to real world problems, so if you want to parse MD to HTML: there are quite a lot of good libraries for that already (including several written in JS that you just `npm install`) and that you can trivially extend to do what you need. "Don't roll your own" is a perfectly valid comment.

Comment: I just need an answer, I believe the reasoning is not the issue of my question.

Comment: As for writing an answer: not yet. Right now this is just a programming basics mistake. You used `if` instead of `else if`, so if that solves your problem, this is guaranteed a duplicate of a whole bunch of other questions already. If it doesn't, then you can update your post with your updated code so that it's at least not just a basic "how do I use multiple if?" question.

Comment: I've been working with Javascript for 6-7 years as you can see in my bio. I know how to use an if statement. I was trying to take a lazy route with a for loop and did not think of this. thank you in advance.

Comment: I trust the code you show, not the bio you write. And the code shows a whole bunch of beginner mistakes.

Comment: Because im lazy.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Also, should I use `case` over `elseif`? I just want outsider's perspective.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, I could have done other things. But I saw it being used awhile ago and thought id try it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans how would I use elseif in this particular case? Mabye you should post an answer

Comment: OK, so you do know the result of say, `let code="1"; code += code.concat("2")` would be `112` and you think that's appropriate for your function?

Comment: @JaromandaX if you could post an answer that works and goes in depth that would help me understand a little better.

Comment: no, I'm pointing out why you get `<h1>` repeated - because you use that incorrect pattern, as for code that results in what you want, I haven't even bothered to check - I would, like someone else suggested, reverse the order of the `if` statements, for obvious reasons, and other obvious things

Comment: `just use Elseif`, AND reverse the order - so, womp womp

Comment: you should ALSO test for 0 or more leading spaces, and ONE or more spaces after the `#` of course - because markdown

Comment: @JaromandaX I thought that wouldn't work, because of the return case like true/false but that's if you were using else. I also decided a crap tone of if statements isn't that high quality soooo....

Comment: @JaromandaX I edited my question after an answer suggested an edit. Before you commented.

Comment: you have 6 if statements - in my opinion that's a crap ton already :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Then how should I make it shorter? I've been trying to improve some of my crappy code habits recently and I don't know what others do or suggest in large applications, yes this one is small but I code websites all the time and just started getting into larger softwsres. All I want to know now is where should i go with this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a better and more general way to handle this.  In addition, it won't strip out "#" that are in the middle of a string, as yours would.  This relies on the fact that a ### header must be followed by a space.

```
function render(md){
    let code = "";

    let mdLines = md.split('\n');

    for(let i = 0; i < mdLines.length; i++){
        
        if(mdLines[i][0] == "#") {
            // We have a header.  How many are there?
            let s = mdLines[i].indexOf(" ")
            if( mdLines[i].slice(0,s) == '#'.repeat(s) )
                code += "<h"+s+">" + mdLines[i].slice(s+1) + "</h"+s+">";
            else
                code += mdLines[i];
        }
        else
            code += mdLines[i];
    };
    
    return code;
}

let text1 = "## he#llo \n there \n # yooo"
let text2 = "# he#llo \n there \n ## yooo"

console.log(render(text1));
console.log(render(text2));
```

Output:

```
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$ node x.js
<h2>he#llo </h2> there  # yooo
<h1>he#llo </h1> there  ## yooo

timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$
```

### Followup

Here's what you apparently MEANT to test with:

```
let text1 = "## he#llo\nthere\n# yooo"
let text2 = "# he#llo\nthere\n## yooo"
```

And here's the output:

```
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$ node x.js
<h2>he#llo</h2>there<h1>yooo</h1>
<h1>he#llo</h1>there<h2>yooo</h2>
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$
```

Comment: It still doesn't return proper MD.

Comment: # yooo in the string should also be outputted as a h1 or h2 tag depending on what string I'm rendering.

Comment: This does not work for what I need. The `code +=` is better direction for it but the second tag isn't in the return.

Comment: Of course it is.  Did you not see my sample output?  I ran this code before I posted it.  Are you talking about the "yooo" lines?  Those are not valid.  In order to be recognized, the hash marks must start in column 1.  That's a markdown rule.

Comment: The text1 variable return should be `<h2>he#llo</h2> there <h1> yooo </h1>` not `<h2>he#llo </h2> there  # yooo`. That why I mentioned it.

Comment: Yes, but it's a render. every where there's `\n` or  an enter is a new line of MD. Rules of MD formating is not my issue.

Comment: Yes, but you have a space after the `\n`.  That makes it invalid.  You have to be precise when working with computers....

Comment: This doesn't work... I can have a `<h100>` tag if I want. It needs a limit up too a h6 heading.

Comment: Come on, you can't be serious.  If you want it to stop at 6 for some reason, then add an "if" statement.  This is not a free custom consulting service.

Comment: @TimRoberts - leading spaces before `#` are allowed in Markdown - so, testing the value of the first character won't work

Comment: @JaromandaX can you post an answer? With short reusable code that follows MD rules? I'm desperate to get a fully complete answer to actually learn from this. If you do you'll have my forever thanks. Please post an answer.

Comment: @JaromandaX You say that with confidence, but you are wrong.  There are a hundred different variations of markdown.  The two I tried do not accept leading spaces.  Indeed, the leading hashtag thing was not part of original markdown at all -- you used a line of ==== or ---- to signal a header.  And if you want to LEARN from this, then use this to produce your final.  Don't force someone else to do your homework for you.

Comment: @TimRoberts The ONE I tried (VS Code markdown viewer) does, hence I didn't try a second, and am filled with confidence :p - as the OP expects it to behave that way, I made the comment - and it's NOT my homework, I'm not the oP

Comment: I agree with @JaromandaX on this one. I would wish for him or her to post their own answer on this instead. I really do want to learn. I may be experienced but that doesn't mean I'm still not perfect or filled with knowledge. Also, this isn't homework just a simple thing I want to learn from.

Comment: @Jerico - what makes you think I HAVE an answer - all I did was point out why your code duplicates the `<h1>` in the first test

Comment: @Jerico - OK, I'll look at it - give me a moment

Comment: @JaromandaX I think that because you've corrected a actual answer on the post and have stated what you'd fix. I've also given you more information through comments wich you have replied to with your knowledge leading me to believe you could give an answer.

Comment: Note that a regex with capture group replacement obviates the need for any loop whatsoever here, and we can destructure the length of `(#{1,6})` to make the conversion a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

After constant requests, I took a look at the expected output, and this is probably not the best/neatest code, but it does work, and is fairly compact

```js
function render(md) {
    let code = ""; //For functions return
    let mdLines = md.split("\n");
    
    const re = /^\s*([#]{1,6})\s/;
    for (let line of mdLines) {
        const hash = line.match(re);
        if (hash) {
            const h = hash[1].length;
            line = `<h${h}>${line.replace(re, "").trim()}</h${h}>`;
        }
        code += line;
    }
    return code;
}

let text1 = "## he#llo \n there \n # yooo";
let text2 = "# he#llo \n there \n ## yooo";

console.log(render(text1));
console.log(render(text2));
```

Comment: Your my saviour in this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing something that does "the same thing, with just one thing changing at each step", that's a loop, or if you foresee a situation that does warrant `if` statements, then you generally want to resolve them such that you handle "the largest thing first" (to ensure there's no fall-through) or by using `if-else` statements (also so there's no fall-though).

You might consider a switch, but the switch statement is a hold-over from programming languages that didn't have dictionaries/key-value objects to perform O(1) lookups with, which JS, Python, etc. all do. So in JS you're almost *always* better off using a mapping object with your case values as property keys, turning an O(n) code path with a switch into an O(1) immediate lookup)

However, in this case what we're really doing is simple text matching, so you can use the best tool in the toolset for that: you can trivially get both the `#` sequence and "remaining text" with a regex, and then generate the replacement HTML [using the captured data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#replacement):

```js
function markdownToHTML(doc) {
  return convertMultiLineMD(doc.split(`\n`)).join(`\n`);
}

function convertMultiLineMD(lines) {
  // convert tables, lists, etc, while also making sure
  // to perform inline markup conversion for any content
  // that doesn't span multiple lines. For the purpose of
  // this answer, we're going to ignore multi-line entirely:
  return convertInlineMD(lines);
}

function convertInlineMD(lines) {
  return lines.map((line) => {
    // convert headings
    line = line.replace(
      // two capture groups, one for the markup, and one for the heading,
      // with a third optional group so we don't capture EOL whitespace.
      /^(#+)\s+(.+?)(\s+)?$/,
      // and we extract the first group's length immediately
      (_, { length: h }, text) => `<h${h}>${text}</h${h}>`
    );
    // then wrap bare text in <p>, convert bold, italic, etc. etc.
    return line;
  });
}

// And a simple test based on what you indicated:
const docs = [`## he#llo\nthere\n# yooo    `, `# he#llo\nthere\n## yooo`];

docs.forEach((doc, i) => console.log(`[doc ${i + 1}]\n`, markdownToHTML(doc)));
```

Note, though, that even this is still a naive approach to writing a transpiler, with rather poor runtime performance compared to writing [a stack parser](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.31.2/#appendix-a-parsing-strategy) or [a DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) based on the markdown grammar (the "markup language specification" grammar, i.e. the rules that say which tokens can follow which other tokens), where you run through your document by tracking what kind of token we're dealing with, and convert on the fly as we pass token terminations.

(This is, in fact, how regular expressions work: they generate a DFA from the [regular grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar) pattern you specify, then run the input through that DFA, achieving near-perfect runtime performance)